# Android: The image inserted in image view does not appear over the existing View

Tags: android, imageview

I have an app to draw on the canvas.  When I try to insert image from the gallery I cannot find the image being inserted in the ImageView.  When I decrease the visibility of the previous view, then I can see the image.  I need to make this image as part of the previous view and continue drawing on it. Following is my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
       Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
       String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

       Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
               filePathColumn, null, null, null);
       cursor.moveToFirst();

       int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
       String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
       cursor.close();

       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
  }
}
```

Comment: is flow reaching inside if block ...... can put a toast to confirm

Comment: Yes.  The flow reaches inside the if block.  I had confirmed it.

Comment: looks fine can you provide more code of this activity with Xml layout...

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Please look into the following layout <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://..." android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <com.tel.scribble.ScribbleView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/scribbleView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/> 
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: thanks you also have option to edit you question and update that for updating the activity code ....

Answer (score 0):

As per you layout given in comment looks scribbleView is match_parent so it will fill the screen and you don't have the ScrollView so are not able to see the image which may be after the scribbleView which is full screen so please try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.tel.scribble.ScribbleView
            android:id="@+id/scribbleView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I am finding the application crashing